# Pandas dataframe select row by index and column by name

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

Is there any way to select the row by index (i.e. integer) and column by column name in a pandas data frame?

I tried using loc but it returns an error, and I understand iloc only works with indexes.

Here is the first rows of the data frame df. I am willing to select the first row, column named 'Volume' and tried using df.loc[0,'Volume']

[image]

Comment: You could provide the index using `df.iloc[0].index`. So the full thing becomes `df.loc[ df.iloc[0].index, 'Volume' ]` (note this is not an efficient solution)

Comment: how about using `.iloc` then column name? `df.iloc[0]['Volume']`

Answer (score 4):

Use `get_loc` method of Index to get integer location of a column name.

Suppose this dataframe:

```
>>> df
    A  B  C
10  1  2  3
11  4  5  6
12  7  8  9
```

You can use `.iloc` like this:

```
>>> df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_loc('B')]
5
```